# How make a collectionView of videos without crashing cause of memory

Tags: swift

On my app, I made a collectionView with video on each cells. Videos can't be more than 1 minute. 
I free the AVPlayer on the prepareForReuse (it's called each time, I swipe until the next cell.) All videos come from the phone, not from url.

So my memory is not growing a lot but It's still growing and at the end can't load more videos... and app crash. The error message is `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.playerLayer?.player?.pause()
    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    self.avasset = nil
}
```

How Do instagram, snapchat and other ? they display thousands video without crashing...

Comment: show how do you populate collectionView with videos

Comment: I think adding `AVPlayer` in each cell is not good idea, instead use one `AVPlayer` and share it to all cell

Comment: it's much better to show thumbnail in the cell with a play icon over the top. on select change to avplayer and play. Snapchat only shows one at a time, or a queue of videos one after the other. you can easily paginate full screen videos by using 3 avplayers. one for previous, current and next

Comment: tear down more.. perhaps also remove the playerLayer from the view? and also set player to nil? (just guesses but I'd probably try that)

Comment: I can't make a play icon. The video has to play automatically. 
And the collectionView is not full screen. 

and when I clean the cell I remove the  playerLayer from the view and set player to nil